# How to generate Hyperlegder Fabric genesis block with/ without configtxgen tool

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I'll go straight to my problems.

All we know that to start a fabric network, we need **a genesis block**. I just know the only way to generate genesis block using **configtxgen** from HF and it requires a config file.
Here is my situation:

***User can choose organizations to create consortium.***

I thought about the way to generate the config file but it doesn't work. I can't define any structs like the config file ( cause they contain & << * character - *go-yaml module didn't help*).

I got two questions:

1. If we can continue with using the config file solution, how we can generate a file with special characters?
2. Is there any way to generate genesis block without **configtxgen**

Additional information. I'm using Fabric 2.2

Any help is appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found the solution. Because Hyperledger Fabric already exported module named **fabric-config@v0.0.9**, we can use this module to create and generate config block. It was pretty upset that they don't tell us in document. Lucky for me when I saw the module and tried.